# Creating a Stack for a RPN Calculator

Tags: c, stack

im a c-starter. I have an issue with creating a Stack for my RPN Calculator. I want to initiallise it with malloc.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h> 


typedef struct _stack stack;
typedef struct _stack_element stack_element;

struct _stack
{
    stack_element *top;
};

struct _stack_element
{
    stack_element *next;
    float value;
};
```

This is how i call the create Stack funktion:

```
stack *astack = stack_create();
```

This is the creation of the Stack:

```
stack *stack_create()
{
    stack *Stack = (stack*)malloc (sizeof(struct _stack));
    return Stack;
}
```

Everythig i tried ended in a segmentation error and at this point i dont know how to solve that.

EDIT: 
Where i use the Stack:

```
process(astack, string);
```

string is my input.

```
void process(stack *astack, char *string)
{
if (token[0] == '+')
    {
        stack_push(astack, stack_pop(astack) + stack_pop(astack));
        return;
    }
... all the other cases ...
}
```

```
float stack_pop(stack *astack)
{
    float value = astack->top->value;
    astack->top = astack->top->next;
    return value;
}
```

```
void stack_push(stack *astack, float value)
{
    astack->top->value = value;
    astack->top->next = astack->top;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.  You aren't setting top = NULL, and the code you aren't showing us where you use the stack might not be allocating new _stack_elelments as needed.  It might help to read [mcve] since we have to guess at the rest of your code to try to help you.  You should edit your question to include enough of the missing code to create a [mcve]

Comment: thanks for the advice @DaveS i Edited my post i hope its now more clear.

Comment: I think it might be easier if you could just post a single code block that's a self-contained C program that demonstrates the issue. Other useful information would be which statement triggers the error and what the exact error message is (that is of course assuming you haven't already fixed the problem based on previous suggestions).

Comment: Agreed.  The code snippets above doesn't show you allocating any _stack_element objects, so of course push will cause memory errors.  If not freeing popped elements that will also cause leaks.

Comment: I think you need to allocate memory for a `struct _stack_element` in `stack_push()` and free it in `stack_pop()`. Of course that's incredibly slow and it'd be much faster and easier to understand if you just did a plain `double myStack[MAX_STACK_SIZE];` with some `void push(double value) { if(top >= MAX_STACK_SIZE) { /* Error */ } else { myStack[top++] = value; } }`.

Comment: ^ definitely simpler.  You'd also need to return an error from `pop` when the stack is empty.